# qqplot and qqline in loop

Tags: r, data-visualization

i am trying to make a loop for each columns in the database.
i am getting this Error: Must use a vector in `[`, not an object of class matrix.
my data looks like this: [image: database str]
and this is my code:

```
for (q in 1:ncol(flat_file_numeric[])) {   
    qqnorm(flat_file_numeric[,q])
    qqline(flat_file_numeric[,q], col= "steelblue",lwd=2)}
```

i will appreciate any help.
thanks.

Comment: Please include sample data in your question using `dput(df)`.

Comment: Please don’t use images of data as they cannot be used without a lot of unnecessary effort. [For multiple reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Best if your question is [reproducible0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: movie_id budget popularity runtime revenue sw_web_presence sw_has_poster sw_tagline keyword_cnt sw_unknown_prod~ release_year release_month high_release_mo~ release_day years_of_war
      <dbl>  <dbl>      <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>           <dbl>         <dbl>      <dbl>       <dbl>            <dbl>        <dbl>         <dbl>            <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>
 1        5 0           1.15      118  3.92e6               1             1          1           0                1         2009             2                0           5            1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without some actual data is it hard to be sure, but from the error message it looks like some problem with the data itself.

I would start by trying this prior to the loop:

```
flat_file_numeric <- as.data.frame(flat_file_numeric)
```

Comment: Thanks @robert long it's actually worked.
p.s- i tried to upload the data using dput or structure but It didn't work so i need to understand it better.

Comment: You're welcome :)  You should be able to just run `dput(flat_file_numeric)` (or just the first few rows if it is too large), then edit the original question and put the output in there.